# Laravel custom validation rule to not allow just punctuation or any emojis in a string

Tags: regex, laravel, validation

I'm not great with RegEx and wondering if someone could help explain how I can go about not allowing the following. I want to block the user from being able to enter any emojis in a string as well as only punctuation. i.e.

```
".."        => fail
"-----"     => fail
",,,,"      => fail
"Mc-Donald" => pass
```

Any emojis in the string should also result in a fail.

I was thinking of setting up a custom Laravel rule for this using regex to check if the string contains only punctuation or any emojis.

Perhaps a better way might be for a RegEx to only allow certain characters? As I only really want to allow only letters, numbers and punctuation (just not only puncation on it's own)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the validation rule `alpha_dash` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-alpha-dash or `alpha_num`. If you want to finetune it, you can use the following code to customize your own regex:

(Add this to a service provider)

```php
Validator::extend('alpha_num_dash', function($attribute, $value) {
    if(!is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value)) {
        return false;
    }
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$/', $value);
});
```

I will not explain the regex meaning here since it is out of scope. Look up a guide and you will quickly learn the ropes of that. Furthermore, you could try an online service like https://regex101.com/r/PxtN3U/1 to tinker with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function [ctype_punct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-punct.php) that "check for any printable character which is not whitespace or an alphanumeric character".

Something like that:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => [
        'required',
        'max:255',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (ctype_punct($value)) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

More detailed validation will require regex, e.g. must contains at least one "alphabetical character":

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => ['required','max:255','regex:/[a-zA-Z]/'],
]);
```